# Вывод найденных и сопряженных Bluetooth устройств в ListView, дублирование устройств в списке

Tags: java, android, listview, bluetooth

я новичок в Android разработке. Возникла проблема вывода bluetooth устройств в ListView. Суть такова, что при запуске приложения выводится список уже сопряженных устройств в ListView, а затем по нажатию кнопки в соседний ListView выводится список найденных устройств. В общем подобно обычному меню bluetooth в настройках.

Изначально все выводилось в один ListView, но потом было решено разделить блоки и из-за этого все окончательно в голове запуталось (я новичок, поэтому листАдаптеры + BT API + тд.тп. вместе даются довольно тяжело). Я же правильно понимаю, что я могу использовать один адаптер для двух списков, т.к. они состоят из одних и тех же элементов?

Помимо этого еще есть проблема дублирования устройств в списке, причем некоторые по несколько раз, предварительная очистка списка не работает, они дублируются по ходу поиска. Скорее всего проблема в самом алгоритме поиска.

На код не ругайтесь, мой первый проект, дальше думаю разбить по разным папкам и файлам

**Код MainActivity:**

```
package com.example.bttest;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener,
        AdapterView.OnItemClickListener,
        View.OnClickListener {


private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;  // Включение BT
public static final int BT_FOUND           = 3;  // Найденные BT устройства

private static final int REQUEST_CODE_LOCATION  = 4; //Данные о местоположении

private Switch btSwitch;               // Switch
private LinearLayout deviceListFrame;  // Фрейм с устоойствами
private ListView bondedDeviceList;     // Список найденных устройств
private ListView foundDeviceList;      // Список сопряженных устройств
private Button btnStartSearch;         // Кнопка "поиск"


private BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;
private ListAdapter listAdapter;
private ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> foundBluetoothDevices;      // Массив найденных устройств
private ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> bondedBluetoothDevices;     // Массив сопряженных устройств



private TextView myDeviceInfo;        // Инфо об устройстве пользователя
private String myDeviceName;          // Имя устройства пользователя
private String myDeviceAddress;       // Адрес устройства пользователя

@SuppressLint("HardwareIds")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btSwitch         = findViewById(R.id.switch_bt_on_off);         // Switch для вкл/выкл BT
    deviceListFrame  = findViewById(R.id.device_list);              // Фрейм с устройствами [обертка]
    bondedDeviceList = findViewById(R.id.lv_bt_devices_bonded);     // Список сопряженных устройств
    foundDeviceList  = findViewById(R.id.lv_bt_devices_found);      // Список найденных устройств
    btnStartSearch   = findViewById(R.id.btn_startSearch);

    myDeviceInfo     = findViewById(R.id.tv_my_device_info);        // Инфо о моем устройстве

    btSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    bondedDeviceList.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    btnStartSearch.setOnClickListener(this);

    foundBluetoothDevices = new ArrayList<>();
    bondedBluetoothDevices = new ArrayList<>();

    bondedDeviceList.setAdapter(listAdapter);

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED);
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);

    IntentFilter searchFilter = new IntentFilter();
    searchFilter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED);
    searchFilter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
    searchFilter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
    registerReceiver(searchReciever, searchFilter);

    bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
     if (bluetoothAdapter == null) {
         Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth не поддерживается устройством", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         finish();
     }

     if (bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
         myDeviceName    = bluetoothAdapter.getName();
         myDeviceAddress = bluetoothAdapter.getAddress();
         myDeviceInfo.setText(myDeviceName + "\n" + myDeviceAddress);
         showDeviceList();
         btSwitch.setChecked(true);
     }


}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    unregisterReceiver(searchReciever);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.equals(btnStartSearch)){
        startSearch();
    }
}

private void startSearch() {
    if (bluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()) {
        bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
    } else {
        accessLocationPermission();
        bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
    }
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

}

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    if (buttonView.equals(btSwitch)) {
        enableBt(isChecked);


        if (!isChecked) {
            hideDeviceList();
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_ENABLE_BT) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            showDeviceList();
            setListAdapter(BT_FOUND);
        }

        else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            btSwitch.setChecked(false);
        }
    }
}

private void showDeviceList() {
    deviceListFrame.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
private void hideDeviceList() {
    deviceListFrame.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

private void enableBt(boolean flag) {
    if (flag) {
        Intent btOn = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(btOn, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
    }
    else {
        bluetoothAdapter.disable();
    }
}

private void setListAdapter(int type) {
    foundBluetoothDevices.clear();
    bondedBluetoothDevices = getBondedBtDevices();
        listAdapter = new ListAdapter(this, foundBluetoothDevices);
        listAdapter = new ListAdapter(this, bondedBluetoothDevices);
        bondedDeviceList.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        foundDeviceList.setAdapter(listAdapter);
}

 private ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> getBondedBtDevices() {
    Set<BluetoothDevice> deviceSet = bluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
    ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> tmpArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    if (deviceSet.size() > 0) {
        for (BluetoothDevice device: deviceSet) {
            tmpArrayList.add(device);
        }
    }
    return tmpArrayList;
 }



private final BroadcastReceiver searchReciever = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
         String action = intent.getAction();

         switch (action) {
            case BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED:
                btnStartSearch.setText("Остановить");
                break;

                case BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED:
                btnStartSearch.setText("Начать поиск");
                break;

                case BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND:
                 BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                 if (device != null) {
                     foundBluetoothDevices.add(device);
                     listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                 }
                 break;
        }
    }
};

/**
 * Слушатель состояния Bluetooth
 **/

private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                final String action = intent.getAction();

                if (action.equals(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED)) {
                    final int state = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_STATE,
                            BluetoothAdapter.ERROR);
                    switch (state) {
                        case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_OFF:
                            btSwitch.setChecked(false);
                            break;
                        case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_OFF:
                            // Turning Bluetooth off...
                            break;
                        case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON:
                            btSwitch.setChecked(true);
                            break;
                        case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_ON:
                            // Turning Bluetooth on...
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        };


@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CODE_LOCATION:

            if (grantResults.length > 0) {
                for (int gr: grantResults) {
                    if (gr != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
        default:
            return;
    }
}

/**
 *Запрос на разрешение получения данных о местоположении (6.0)
 **/
private void accessLocationPermission() {
    int accessCoarseLocation = this.checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
    int accessFineLocation   = this.checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);

    List<String> listRequestPermission = new ArrayList<String>();

    if (accessCoarseLocation != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        listRequestPermission.add(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
    }
    if (accessFineLocation != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        listRequestPermission.add(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
    }

    if (!listRequestPermission.isEmpty()) {
        String[] strRequestPermission = listRequestPermission.toArray(new String[listRequestPermission.size()]);
        this.requestPermissions(strRequestPermission, REQUEST_CODE_LOCATION);
    }
}
}
```

**Код ListAdapter:**

```
public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private static final int RESOURCE_LAYOUT = R.layout.list_item;
    private ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> bluetoothDevices;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public ListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> bluetoothDevices) {
        this.bluetoothDevices = bluetoothDevices;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return bluetoothDevices.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return getItem(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(RESOURCE_LAYOUT, parent, false);

        BluetoothDevice device = bluetoothDevices.get(position);
        if (device != null) {
            ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.device_name)).setText(device.getName());
            ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.device_address)).setText(device.getAddress());
            if (device.getBondState() == 12) {
                ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.icon_bound)).setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_bluetooth_bounded);
            }
            else if (device.getBondState() == 10) {
                ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.icon_bound)).setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_bluetooth_no_bounded);
            }
        }
        return view;
    }
}
```

**UPD:**

1. Вопрос с выводом в ListView решил просто создав такой же адаптер для второго списка, хотя в принципе почти получилось оба списка заполнять одним адаптером, но видимо были кое-какие конфликты между ними из-за чего иногда один из списков не заполнялся (уверен что можно обойтись одним адаптером, но пока туповат чтобы это нормально реализовать).
2. Вопрос с дублированием решился добавлением дополнительной проверки (код в комментарии)

Comment: "Я же правильно понимаю, что я могу использовать один адаптер для двух списков, т.к. они состоят из одних и тех же элементов" - Можно использовать один __класс__ адаптера, но вот объекты создавайте разные! И перед добавлением элементов после поиска, делайте проверку, не добавили ли Вы устройство в найденные раньше

Comment: @Alex_Skvortsov, все починил. Оба листа делает один адаптер, просто получает разные массивы на вход. Но проблема с дублированием устройств при поиске осталась (проблема не в том что устройство уже есть в списке сопряженных, а в том, что найденное устройство отображается дважды)

Comment: `if (device != null && !foundBluetoothDevices.contains(device) {
                     foundBluetoothDevices.add(device);
                     listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                 }`

Comment: @blind.falcon, `if (device != null && device.getBondState() != 12) {
                         foundBluetoothDevices.add(device);
                         foundListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` По сути точно такое же решение, но проблема не в этом, а в том что найденное устройство отображается дважды в списке (https://imgur.com/a/CHquISp)

Comment: Ваш код находится в адаптере и работает с уже заполненным списком, то есть он лишь проверят сопряжено устройство или нет, и если нет выводит, всё включая дубликаты. Но сам список формируется там где я показал и проверять надо там.

Comment: @blind.falcon, О, действительно, добавил проверку массива и все работает, благодарю!    `if (device != null && !foundBluetoothDevices.contains(device)  && device.getBondState() != 12) {                          foundBluetoothDevices.add(device);                          foundListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`